# Attach event handler from parent class in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, events, inheritance

I have a base class for a window that contains a number of event handlers common for my windows of this type (they fire common validation methods).

Here is an example event handler:

```
protected virtual void ValidateTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ValidateProperty((FrameworkElement)sender, TextBox.TextProperty);
}
```

and there are approximately 20 of these, covering the common controls.

Each window instance is built from a child class of the base. In the .xaml of the child class I do:

```
<TextBox 
    TextChanged="ValidateTextBoxTextChanged"/>
```

But when I navigate to this window, I get the following error:

> Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.TextChanged'.

So it's not finding the event handler. Is there an elegant way I can assign the event handlers without duplicating them in every child class (~ 30 children and counting)?

Comment: Please show a more complete code example. At the very least, it needs to show the full context, i.e. what class the method is in, how that class relates to your XAML, and of course the context in the XAML itself as well. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's interesting -- it seems to be a limitation of the event mechanism to only check the partial code-behind class, and not its base class.  (This issue has also been raised [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/fd753f2b-c304-4d39-9ae7-478504867776/impossible-to-add-event-handler-to-user-control-base-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5482872/1001985).)  I can't think of an ideal work-around, either.

Of course, you could fix the error by putting a dummy override in every child class:

```
protected override void ValidateTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.ValidateTextBoxTextChanged(sender, e);
}
```

Now, granted that seems like a hassle.  An alternative would be to use a trigger/action combination to call the base-class method:

```
<TextBox>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:BaseWindow}}"  MethodName="ValidateTextBoxTextChanged" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

For this, you would need to make the method public.  You could use variations on the above to simplify the syntax and reduce the number of bindings: use an attached property to apply the trigger, put the validation method in static resources with an optional override.

---

Another possible approach would be to subclass `TextBox` itself, and place your validation logic there.  You could expose a dependency property to allow instances of your extended TextBox to override the default validation logic.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working in code. I have a base xaml page that has few descendats

```
<Page x:Class="mycls"><Button x:Name="mybrn"/></Page>
```

And some view that inherit it:

```
<local:mycls x:Class="mychild"></local:mycls>
```

If I assign listener in xaml, it doesn't work in child view. But in code-behind it works:

```
public mycls()
{
    InitializeComponent()
    (this.FindName("mybtn") as Button).Click += mybtn_click;
}
```

After this child view "inhherit" also a handler.